# Call the _mint function of an ERC1155 contract in the fulfillRandomWords callback

Tags: chainlink, erc-1155, mint, vrf, chainlink-vrf

I want to call the `_mint` function of an ERC1155 contract in the `fulfillRandomWords`  callback but i'm getting an error, i guess is due to max fee reached.

How can i solve this?

```
    function fulfillRandomWords(    
        uint256 _requestId,
        uint256[] memory _randomWords
    ) internal override {
        require(s_requests[_requestId].exists, "request not found");

        s_requests[_requestId].fulfilled = true;
        s_requests[_requestId].randomWords = _randomWords;
        emit RequestFulfilled(_requestId, _randomWords);

        _mint(s_requests[_requestId].account, s_requests[_requestId]._id, s_requests[_requestId].amount, "");
    }
```

Comment: Do you know how much your mint function will cost? If you call it by itself outside of `fulfillRandomWords`, that should give you an idea. You would then need to make sure that the `callbackGasLimit`is set to more than that amount